# Dynamically add Items to ListView with Efficient Adapter

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me, How am I load an image at runtime in listview with the help of efficientAdapter in android.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're thinking about [Efficient Adapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html) sample code from [Api Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html).